# GAS Regex, Can someone turn make this regex to work in App Script?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

From this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url),([What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url))

we can use regular expression to match a lot of URL,( it works as testing in regex website. somehow it is not working in GAS(Google App Script )  since using it as

```
   var rx = 'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)';

     regex= string.match(rx)
     Logger.log(regex)
```

It always return null as

```
Info    null
```

However this regex works on this page https://regexr.com. How can we make it works with GAS?

How can we match something like this in GAS?

```
https://notifications.example.com/f/g/FB-FnExAZJUxP7fPZCGR4kW9FodXg0X1GBR4wZ0GUaAV0DgL3xUT1K2gBsxnQVcGbzPcydEWIwOgDQ-GiVzMERg5FPGm1Ek6YWnAyElHsz5uqJe5wYYtgQbGuQmW5WxF6E8bu9CfRtBEJ7AWDxWSwfOu__Ahwrwsnw
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be `var rx = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/`;

Comment: Checkout the answers on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Comment: not really. it returns only two URLs. while it should matched a lot.
can you help me match this url ?

https://notifications.example.com/f/g/FB-FnExAZJUxP7fPZCGR4kW9FodXg0X1GBR4wZ0GUaAV0DgL3xUT1K2gBsxnQVcGbzPcydEWIwOgDQ-GiVzMERg5FPGm1Ek6YWnAyElHsz5uqJe5wYYtgQbGuQmW5WxF6E8bu9CfRtBEJ7AWDxWSwfOu__Ahwrwsnw

Comment: perhaps you need the g flag as in `/g`

Comment: Read the links I gave you.  I suspect they know more about it than I do.

Comment: read the link before posting the question here,  Not sure if all my URL starts with notification.domain.com  or something else. (since most url started with www.domain.com ) Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns only two URLs. while it should matched a lot"? Provide the list of urls that should match and what doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because it is *not* using a regex. It is simply matching one text string against another.

To make it work, use a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), like this:

```
const rx = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/i;
```

If you need to use a text string literal for some reason, double escape the text string using `\\` in place of `\`, and apply the [RegExp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor to make a regex of it.